# Fix singularity in numpy matrix for scipy interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I want to do RBF interpolation in scipy using three input numpy arrays and an output array. The data is in the following format.

```
x1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 10, 10]
x2 = [-3, -2.5, ..., 7.5, 7.5]
x3 = [200, 500, 700, ..., 1600, 1600]

y = [7, 8, 9, ..., 40, 42]

spline = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x1, x2, x3, y)
```

While the content of the data doesn't matter, there are some input entries for which we are seeing multiple output entries and interpolation will fail because of this.

I want to fix this singularity using a condition that if inputs are the same then only keep the value with minimum y. So in our case only the last value of 40 will be kept while 42 needs to be discarded. What is the fastest way of doing this using numpy operations.

Since this data can be large I don't want to iterate over the entire range. I can use `np.unique(np.array([x1, x2, x3]).T, axis=0)`, to get only unique entries but I want the corresponding minimum value in y to also be picked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below

```
    x1 = [2, 5,10, 10] 
    x2 = [-3, -2.5,7.5, 7.5]
    x3 = [200, 500,1600, 1600]
    y = [7, 8, 40, 42]
    
    pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1,'x2':x2,'x3':x3,'y':y}).groupby(['x1','x2','x3']['y'].min().to_list()
```

The answer will be [7, 8, 40]